# WooCommerce: Custom my account endpoint & permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a custom my account endpoint created using this method: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/tabbed-my-account-pages-in-2-6/

My custom endpoint and my account tab is 'support-tickets'.

Inside of that new tab, I've got a pagination function that shows links as `/my-account/support-tickets/?page=2`, but when clicking on the links returns the base `/my-account/2` URL and just shows my main Dashboard tab.

I've tried adjusting the `add_query_vars` function like so:

```
public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = self::$endpoint;
    $vars[] = 'page';
    return $vars;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any thoughts or ideas? Is this possible to have pagination work within the custom endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had resaved permalinks (with /%postname%/ option) in wp-admin settings area when you added new custom endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this every time I make any changes to the custom endpoint :)